# ctx.commandFailed vs throwing in PersistentEntity

Tags: lagom

In the [Auction Example](https://github.com/lagom/online-auction-scala) I have seen both `ctx.commandFailed(...)` and `throw SomeException(...)`. Is there a good reason to throw instead of using the API and is there a difference between the two?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Persistent entity command handlers and after persist callbacks are wrapped in `try/catch` blocks, if an exception is caught, it will pass that exception to `ctx.commandFailed(...)` for you.

There is a subtle difference between the two to be aware of. If you throw an exception, processing of the command will of course stop immediately. If however you pass an exception to `ctx.commandFailed(...)`, that will send the exception back to the invoker of the command, however it won't stop processing.  You could in theory go on to return some directives to persist events - which would be an odd thing to do. In practice what you need to do is return `ctx.done` after invoking `ctx.commandFailed(...)`.

In general it's probably simpler and safer to simply throw the exception.

Comment: I thought I understood the two options to be relatively equal but what I'm seeing is that throwing an exception leads to logging from the OneToOneStrategy (ostensibly due to the actor being restarted).  I don't see the same logging with ctx.commandFailed(throwable), so it seems that there are material differences.  I don't really want my entity to log every command failed, so I chose the latter.  But I'm wondering if there are other differences.